# Mapping $2$ kinds of operators?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, applications, map-projections

So $z$ from complex analysis can be mapped as:

$$ z \to \hat z = \begin{pmatrix}
\Re z \\
\Im z
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now the $+$ in complex analysis seems to be the same operation as the $+$ in linear algebra. So can one map the pluses to each other?

$$ + \to +$$

It seems like a good redundancy of symbols. I clearly can't be the first one to think of mapping operators? This seems like a natural question to ask. What is the application of this kind of maths?

P.S: This was inspired by [Contour integration in matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410972/contour-integration-in-matrices)

Answer (score 0):

You have rediscovered the fact that $\mathbb C$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$. You want to learn about *linear algebra*.

Comment: But this is a kind of "mapping operators" right? That feel's a bit like the mapping of (mappings between sets) ... Thats what I was going on about

Comment: I guess what I'm going on about is that I feel you should learn some linear algebra.  Then you can bandy buzz words like "operator" and "mapping"  with greater precision and authority.

Comment: Sounds like a comment rather than an answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "application for this kind of maths" but operators and the sets they operate on get mapped all the time.  The general term is [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) if the underlying elements are mapped $1$-to-$1$ (as in your example), or more generally [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) if many-to-$1$ maps are allowed.  The concept can be even further abstracted as [morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism).

Comment: But this is a kind of "mapping operators" right? That feel's a bit like the mapping of (mappings between sets)

Comment: Well, an iso/homo/morphism maps both the operator and the elements simultaneously.  It would only make sense to map operators, if you also map the elements the operators operate on, right?  If not, how would you know if the mapping between operators even make sense?  Perhaps I am not understanding your question...

Comment: I think operators can be defined the mapping between the elements. But I've perhaps just never heard of mapping between these mappings?

Comment: Surely, one can classify different mappings differently?